# Removing Hidden Fonts in Powerpoint

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, xml

Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit/Powerpoint Office 16

Hello all,

I am creating a presentation that should be edited by others, therefore I am embedding the fonts I am using. I started from a third-party template I found online. When I go to save the files, it tells me that font "Titillium" cannot be embedded. I do not use Titillium in the slides - I imagine it was what the template owner used. I have done the following to try to remove or replace the font:

1. Manually check all slides
2. Use "Replace fonts" automation
3. Check and change all Master slides
4. Check and change all Notes
5. Check and change Notes master and Handouts master

At this point I decided to try to edit the XML files. I found the slides where Titillium is present when searching the XML files. I replaced them all with Arial and saved the files, but when I opened them again, they reverted back to Titillium. It should be noted I made these changes without extracting the XML files from the archive. When I then tried to extract the files, I made the changes, converted into an archive, and changed the file extension to *pptx. Powerpoint could then not open the file, it was corrupted.

To troubleshoot, I simply extracted the archive and remade the archive without making any changes, and Powerpoint still could not open the file.

At this point I would need the following the solutions:

1. Replacing the hidden fonts within Powerpoint
2. Instructions on how to convert an XML package back into a *.pptx successfully
3. Some other solution that allows me to save the file with embedded fonts without getting this alert (I am afraid the alert would confuse people who need to edit the file).

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Re 2) Install 7-Zip (https://www.7-zip.org/).  It's a free, open-source program that, among other useful features, can directly open PPTX/PPSX/etcx files w/o having to rename them. You can tell it what program you want to use as your editor and open the files within the PPTX for editing. It's smart enough to do that then update the PPTX with the edited files automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I did use 7-zip but the changes I made were reverted after saving.

Comment: Using 7-zip and using it as I described might be two different things. Did you extract the files to a folder and edit from there, or did you configure 7zip to use your editor of choice and edit from inside the PPTX opened in 7Zip, which is what I suggested.

Comment: Hi Steve, I don't understand what you mean by "edit from inside the PPTX opened in 7Zip." I right clicked on the pptx, opened with 7Zip, then found the xml files in that directory, opened those in dreamweaver and edited there. saved back into the package and the changes were reverted.

Comment: You should rightclick the PPTX and choose Open Archive. In 7Zip, choose Tools | Options | Editor and set the Editor to whatever TEXT editor you want to use.   To edit any of the xml files, click to select the file then press F4. When done, save the file and quit the editor. 7Zip will ask if you want to update it in the archive; click OK.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I followed your instructions and I face the same problem as before - 7Zip does not ask me if I want to update the archive. I save the file and quite the editor, 7Zip does not ask me anything. I then open the xml file again to check and the changes have been reverted.

Comment: I think I see the problem now - I tried again to edit the files in Notepad instead of Dreamweaver, and 7Zip prompted me to update. There must be an issue with Dreamweaver communicating with 7Zip.

Comment: I managed to remove all the instances of Titillium from the slides. I then removed it from the "app.xml" file. I manually searched the rest of the archive and found no more cases of Titillium. I then opened the file back in Powerpoint, and Titillium was still in the list of used fonts. I attempted to save the file and got the same alert about Titillium. I reopened the app.xml file and found Titillium was back. Something must be auto-populating it into the app.xml file, but I cannot find it anywhere else in the entire archive.

Comment: In the end I had to bite the bullet and install the problem font and embed it. I still cannot replace it but at least I don't get the alert.

Comment: For future reference, the font names can be stashed away in all sorts of dark corners. You need to check each of the files in these folders: docProps, ppt
ppt\theme, ppt\slides, ppt\SlideMasters, ppt\SlideLayouts, ppt\notesSlides, ppt\notesMasters, ppt\handoutMasters, ppt\charts and to make things more entertaining, sometimes the names are stored in Chinese/Japanese/Korean or other character sets, even though they're shown in PPT's font lists in roman characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep points to add to the below comment on using 7zip, so need to post as a new answer... I also tried the 7zip method and it did not update the power point file after the internal changes. So what I did was:

1. Extract all the files in the ppt using 7zip into a folder on my desktop
2. Used FileLocator Pro to search the contents of those files and find which included the offending fonts. In my case it was '..\docProps\app.xml' and '..\slideMasters\slideMaster2.xml'
3. Opened those files one at a time in notepad and changed all instances of the missing font to Arial. For example, one was called HelveticaNeueBoldCond and I just replaced all instances of that in the file with Arial. When done I saved the file.
4. When done with the file updates, I opened the original ppt in 7zip again, went to the location of the files e.g. to the docProps folder and deleted the file there (in this case app.xml) - 7zip asked to confirm & said yes. Then I dragged the same file I had edited from my desktop into the 7zip open package. 7zip asked to confirm and said yes. Then I did the same for the slideMaster2.xml file and then closed 7zip.
5. And that was that. For me, no more error messages when I went to save the ppt after opening it.

I guess I can now go hunt in the slide master from within powerpoint and see where those arials are now trying to be used.